# \scriptstyle doesn't propagate into the output of \gls{…} when using latex+dvips

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, glossaries-extra, dvi, dvi-mode

Feeding mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%%% The documentation of glossaries tells to load hyperref first. But this triggers a bug …
\usepackage[style=long3colheader,toc]{glossaries}%%% or glossaries-extra.
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Nat}{name={\(\mathbb{N}\)}, text=\mathbb{N}, sort=n, description={The set of natural numbers.}}
\begin{document}
\(\gls{Nat}^{\gls{Nat}}\)
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

to `latex mwe && makeglossaries mwe && latex mwe && makeglossaries mwe && latex mwe` followed by `dvips mwe` or `dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe` yields

[image: output]

The superscript ℕ is normal size, whereas it should be visibly smaller.

Who is the culprit and what to do?  (Surely you can argue to use pdflatex or lualatex, but for tons of legacy documents, it's not an option.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is dvips specific, as there links are boxed.

Comment: I would disable links for glossary entries, either completly or at least in math. See 5.1.6. Enabling and Disabling Hyperlinks to Glossary Entries in the documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Disabling the links in math mode works for the MWE. I ran into other issues while trying to maintain text-mode hyperlinks (the long glossarized text won't break at the line end, and trying to improve this with hypdvips pushes certain stuff down into the footer space of the page). So, most likely, I'm going to disable all hyperlinks as you said. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  It moreover turns out that glossaries v4.52 sometimes adds additional horizontal space before a glossary-entry link even when hyperlinks are off, so I have to switch from glossaries to glossaries-extra. For glossaries-extra, is the command for turning off the hyperlinks the same, i.e., `\glsdisablehyper`?

Comment: If glossaries inserts unwanted spaces you should make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer First, I thought that glossaries has intentionally been left stable (and, alas, with bugs) compared to glossaries-extra. Second, my registration at dickimaw-books failed (and Nicola knows this), and I retried with another e-mail address now, and this other one failed, too (for a technical reason unknown to me). For glossaries-extra, is the command for turning off the hyperlinks the same, i.e., `\glsdisablehyper`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The bug report http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684369/glossaries-spurious-space-before-the-glossarized-item-at-the-start-of-a-line created.