# glossaries: spurious space before the glossarized item at the start of a line

Tags: glossaries, dvi, dvi-mode, horizontal-spacing, whatsit

Feeding mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[style=long3colheader,toc]{glossaries}% using v4.52. If instead we use glossaries-extra v1.50, the superfluous space goes away.
\usepackage{pstricks}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{productOrder}{name={product order}, text={\sqsubseteq}, sort=productOrder, description={Given posets $(X_i,{\le_i})$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, the \emph{product order} on $L=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is defined by $(a_i)_{i=1}^n\sqsubseteq (b_i)_{i=1}^n$ iff $\forall\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu i\in\mathbb{N}_n: a_i\le_i b_i$ ($(a_i)_{i=1}^n, (b_i)_{i=1}^n\in L$).}, user1={\not{\sqsubseteq}}}
\begin{document}
Consider the lattice $L=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{P}(D_i)$ equipped with the usual product order $\gls{productOrder}$ $=$ $\{((X_i)_{i=1}^n,(X_i')_{i=1}^n)\in L^2\mid \forall\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu i\in\mathbb{N}_n\colon X_i\subseteq X_i'\}$ and the least element $\bot=(\emptyset)_{i=1}^n$.
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

to `latex mwe && makeglossaries mwe && latex mwe && makeglossaries mwe && latex mwe && dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY mwe` yields

[image: output]

There's a spurious space before ⊑ on the second line.  It shouldn't be there.  If we use glossaries-extra instead of glossaries, the superfluous space goes away.  Nicola, could you please update glossaries?

PS. Not filing at dickimaw-books.com because my registration there failed first, and when I took another attempt and finally managed to register there, I got redirected to a maintenance Web site.